# Does the average momentum vanish for an eigenstate of the simple harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose we have a simple harmonic oscillator, let's consider the ground state, $|0\rangle$ and the first excited state $|1\rangle$.

$\langle 0|\hat p|0 \rangle$ is zero right? Since the particle can either be travelling to the left or right, where $\hat p$ is the momentum operator.

Similarly, I think $\langle 1|\hat p|1 \rangle = 0$

But, $\langle 0 | \hat p | 1 \rangle$ is non-zero, right? Since they are different states. Also, since $\hat p$ is Hermitian, $\langle 0 | \hat p | 1 \rangle = \langle 1 | \hat p | 0 \rangle $, right?

Comment: Why don't you try to compute the integral?

Comment: Better yet use raising and lowering operators and compute.

Comment: Or even better yet, use the parity-invariance of the Hamiltonian :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your correct intuition stems from a symmetry of the Hamiltonian called parity invariance, which means that it is the same under reflection (so there is nothing to distinguish left and right). Try looking at the parity operator, i.e. the unitary operation $\Pi$ that takes $x\to -x$ and $p\to - p$. Specifically, you can write $\Pi x\Pi = -x$ and $\Pi p \Pi = -p$. You should also be able to show that:

1) The Hamiltonian commutes with $\Pi$ (since $\Pi H \Pi = H$) and therefore the energy eigenstates $\lvert n \rangle$ are eigenstates of $\Pi$.

2) $\Pi^2 = 1$. What does this tell you about the eigenvalues $\pi_n$ of $\Pi$?

3) $\langle n \rvert p \lvert n \rangle = \langle n \rvert \Pi^2 p \Pi^2 \lvert n \rangle = - \pi_n^2 \langle n \rvert p \lvert n \rangle$. Why does this imply that $\langle n \rvert p \lvert n \rangle = 0$?

Finally, your last point does not follow from the Hermiticity of $p$. Actually you have only the weaker condition $\langle 0\rvert p \lvert 1 \rangle = \left(\langle 1\rvert p^{\dagger} \lvert 0 \rangle\right)^{\ast} = \langle 1\rvert p \lvert 0 \rangle^{\ast}.$

Comment: Sorry, $\hat p$ here means momentum, and not parity operator

Comment: @user44840 I understood the question, have you read my post carefully? It is precisely about the matrix elements of the **momentum** operator, which is $p$ in my notation. (I write the parity operator as $\Pi$, and its eigenvalues are $\Pi|n\rangle = \pi_n|n\rangle$.) You can infer the answers to a lot of your questions, as well as understanding why they are so, by considering the symmetries of the Hamiltonian. In particular, your intuition that the particle "can be travelling to the left or the right" is formalised mathematically in my answer.

Comment: why is $\Pi x\Pi = -x$?

Comment: @user44840 Well, one way to see it is just that this property is actually part of a mathematical definition of $\Pi$. Physically, this definition arises because $\Pi$ represents spatial reflection, i.e. you replace the system by its mirror image, where the mirror is placed at the origin $x=0$. If you reflect the system in this way, any measurement of distance $x$ in your old coordinate system is transformed to the value $-x$ in the new, reflected coordinate system. Likewise, the momentum transforms as $p=-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \to -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial (-x)} = -p$.

Comment: @user44840 One way to implement this transformation is to just take any wavefunction $\psi(x)$ and replace it by $\psi(-x)$. More abstractly, it turns out that this procedure can be represented as a unitary operation. If you modify the states in this way, you must apply a corresponding transformation of the operators like $\Pi p \Pi$.

Comment: I get the operation of the parity operator. But shouldn't it be just $\Pi p = - p$?

Comment: Imagine you want to evaluate the expectation value of the position operator on some parity-transformed state $|\psi^{\prime}\rangle=\Pi |\psi\rangle$. This is
$$\langle \psi^{\prime}|\hat{x} |\psi^{\prime}\rangle = \left(\langle \psi|\Pi^{\dagger} \right)\hat{x}\left( \Pi |\psi\rangle \right)= \langle \psi|\left(\Pi^{\dagger} \hat{x} \Pi \right)|\psi\rangle. $$ So, we get the same result whether we act from the left on the state like $\Pi |\psi\rangle$, or leave the state the same but change the position operator to $\Pi^{\dagger} \hat{x} \Pi$.

Comment: Still, it doesn't show why $\Pi x\Pi = -x$?

Comment: @user44840 If we actually compute the integrals, we find that
$$ \left(\langle \psi|\Pi^{\dagger} \right)\hat{x}\left( \Pi |\psi\rangle \right) = \int dx\, \psi^{\ast}(-x) x \psi(-x) = -\int dx \,\psi^{\ast}(x) x \psi(x) =\int dx \,\psi^{\ast}(x) [- x] \psi(x), $$ after changing variables from $x$ to $-x$. Comparing this with what I have written above, you see that $\Pi^{\dagger} x \Pi = -x$. Finally, since you can easily show that $\Pi^2 = 1$, it follows that $\Pi^{\dagger} = \Pi$, since $\Pi$ is unitary. The proof that $\Pi$ is unitary would be tedious in this small space but it's not hard.

Comment: How did you get from the second to the third step?

Comment: @user44840 Changed variables from $x\to -x$.

Comment: And $\langle 0 | \hat p | 1 \rangle = \langle 1 | \hat p | 0 \rangle$ because the first two states of a SHM are real

Comment: @user44840 Correct. Remember you can always multiply the states $|n\rangle$ by arbitrary complex phases though, in which case your assertion is not necessarily true. It is conventional (and indeed convenient) to define the states to be real.

Comment: So this means that the average momentum for any eigenstate of the HO is 0?